# K2 Item page breaks in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla

Is it possible to make page breaks functional in K2 items? I'm running K2 2.5.5 on Joomla 2.5 with JCE.

Comment: Which version of K2 are you running? K2 have different versions, if you could provide the version we could probably help you more on it. Alternatively, i think k2 support is pretty decent in helping out as well.

Answer (score 0):

no you must use a joomla plugin to do this.
Try this : k2 pagebreak in the JED.
The one i use on my k2 site : PageBreakMyJspace.
With this one, you can also add a table of content directly inside your K2 items.